# Creating class from XML using LINQ, but TargetInvocationException when using namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but I am following an example that worked on some other projects for importing an XML file and treating it like a class. So content like:

```
<Book>
   <Author>Johnny Appleseed</Author>
</Book>
```

Can be accessed in C# using:

```
Book.Author
```

The example I've used creates a public class that inherits XTypedElement, uses its .Load method to open an XML, and then uses LINQ to create properties. So for example,

```
public class Book: XTypedElement, IXMetaData
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<XName, Type> authorDictionary = new Dictionary<XName, Type>();
    private static readonly ContentModelEntity authorContent;

    static Book()
    {
        authorDictionary .Add(XName.Get("Author", ""), typeof(string));
        authorContent= new SequenceContentModelEntity(new NamedContentModelEntity(XName.Get("Author", "")));
    }

    public string Author
    {
        get
        {
            var x = Element(XName.Get("Author", ""));
            return XTypedServices.ParseValue<string>(x, XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.String).Datatype);
        }
        set
        {
            SetElement(XName.Get("Author", ""), value, XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.String).Datatype);
        }
    }

    public static Book Load(string xmlFile)
    {
        return File.Exists(xmlFile) ? XTypedServices.Load<Book>(xmlFile) : null;
    }
}
```

This seems to work really well. Classes representing complex types can be nested using a similar structure. However, all of this breaks as soon as the root node of the XML has a namespace.

```
<Book xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" > THIS WORKS
<Book xmlns="ThisIsAValue" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" > THIS DOESN'T
```

A TargetInvocationException is thrown, with the message "Element is not an instance of Type Book".
There is an XSD that maps to this class, maybe that isn't set up right. I'm not sure. It'd be nice to know where to start looking.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being every instances of XName used throughout my class (which was a lot).

```
// XName.Get is overloaded. If you pass two parameters, the second one is expected to be the namespace of the XML.
XName.Get("Author", "")));
```

Furthermore, my effort seems to be wasted! I just found the sample I was using is based on an open source project found [here](https://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/), where they provide an executable to *generate* these classes for you. Done and done.